# If data exists, else... using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries at the moment, returning the same data, I want the second query to run if the first returns no results, here's the basic idea of my PHP right now:

```
Run Query1
If Query1 returns a result
    Enter data into array
Else 
    Run Query2
    Enter data into array
```

What I'm wondering, is can I do that exclusively using Oracle SQL? So it'd just run a single query to the database, do a quick check of the first statement, and if no results are found run the second one?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of queries?  Are they both `SELECT`s?  Do they return compatible records?

Comment: Yes, and yes - sorry to be vague in my original post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QUERY1
UNION ALL
QUERY2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (QUERY1)
```

e.g:

```
SELECT id
  FROM products
    UNION ALL 
SELECT  id
  FROM old_products
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id  FROM products)
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Table 
WHERE ID = 7 
    AND Flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
    FROM Table 
WHERE ID = 7 
    AND NOT EXISTS (select * from Table where ID = 7 and Flag = 1)
```

To identifiy unique rows you can try this as well:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.* ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY  Flag DESC ) rn
        FROM Table a
    WHERE ID = 7  -- THIS CAN BE PARAMETERIZED
)
SELECT * 
    FROM qry
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this returns two results for some reason, I only need the 1 ;o

Comment: It works fine in my test db. Can you post sample ddl and data?

Comment: To add some context, I'm trying to get the info for a current member of staff (using the flag), but if there isn't one, check people who have left too. It's a horrible system with occasional duplicate IDs, hence I can't just do a blanket search on ID.

Comment: @xn dx: Updated the post with the query. Pls chk

Comment: @xn dx: Updated the answer with another version which uses WINDOW Functions to achieve the same.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you! Just realised it was working before, but there were two leavers - hence the two results! Argh! So sorry to mess you around, this system is so horrible to work with though, duplicate unique IDs: is there anything worse? Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Comment: Suggested alternative: `QUERY1 UNION QUERY2 MINUS QUERY1;`

Comment: @onedaywhen: This would result in rows from Query2 though Query1 picked up some rows

Answer (score 2):

You can put the 2nd query and the associated logic into the when "no_data_found" exception. For example:

```
begin
Query 1
do stuff

exception when no_data_found then
query 2
do stuff
end;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks, just tried this but get an ORA-06550 error, using this code: http://pastebin.com/veb1kxJ3 - any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Semi-colons are required after the Select statements. Just for clarification after looking at your code and other comments, this will not union two record sets. It attempts the first query and if nothing is returned, will fall to the exception block, where you can execute the 2nd query. If you expect to get some results from each, a union may be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

PLSQL (Oracle's flavor of sql) can do IF-THEN-ELSE statements -- here's a sample that should do what you need...

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php

Comment: Many thanks, I looked at this before posting but couldn't figure out how to tailor it to this situation :(

Answer (score 1):

can the second query run even if the first returns results?

if so, then a `UNION` would do it.

if not, then i think UNION is still the right answer, just write the second query WHERE clasue to restrict when the first query records exist.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I'll give it a try and see if I can restrict it to one row