# Oracle DB - If result of Query1 is empty try Query2

Tags: oracle

I have 'inherited' a database application (based on an Oracle 10g database and written in Delphi), which has to make several decisions as follows:

```
Do Query1.
If the result set is empty, do Query2.
```

The queries are `SELECT` queries having the same output columns and sometimes similar (Case 1) and sometimes different (Case 2) input (FROM) and conditions (WHERE).

**Case 1:** Sometimes the difference is: `col like 'x'` (or col = 'x') becomes `col like '%'`.

- Performance:  it probably would be best to use two different queries (`col = 'x'` and the other query without it).
- Maintainability: `col like :param` is better as it does not need 2 queries
- Compromise solution: `AND (col = 'x' OR :param = 1)`

**Case 2:** Another time I have to use a completly different Query2 if there is no data in the resultset of Query1.

---

From searching [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321444/if-data-exists-else-using-oracle-sql) and the internet I am aware of several solutions to my problem:

1. Using two SQL queries: Let the program do the work instead of the database (but needs to query the database twice instead of only once)

   ```
   result = executeQuery(Query1)
   if (isEmpty(result))
   result = executeQuery(Query2)
   ```
2. Using UNION: Let Oracle do all the work (but needs to execute Query1 twice):

   ```
   Query1 UNION ALL Query 2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Query 1)
   ```
3. Using PL/SQL: Let Oracle do most of the work (but I read somewhere that the queries are compiled each time this way)

   ```
   begin
    Query1;
   exception when no_data_found then
    Query2;
   end;
   ```

---

My questions are:

1. Are there other (better) solutions?
2. What would you (as a more experienced database user than me) use?
3. What are the (dis)advantages?
4. What are the caveats?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, you can avoid the `UNION` by using the less strict `WHERE` clause, but include a `ORDER BY` clause so the better matching result appears first. If necessary, you can use the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn to restrict the result to the first one.

For example, instead of

```
 BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO myrec FROM mytable WHERE xxx = 'x';
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     SELECT * INTO myrec FROM mytable WHERE xxx like '%x%';
 END;
```

you could write

```
 SELECT * INTO myrec FROM (
   SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE X like '%x%'
     ORDER BY CASE when xxx='x' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
 ) WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Note the nested `SELECT` statements; this is necessary because otherwise, the `WHERE ROWNUM=1` clause would limit the result set before the `ORDER BY` takes place.